# Shade the area between two axhline using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

What I'm trying to achieve: a plot with two axhline horizontal lines, with the area between them shaded.

The best so far:

```
    ax.hline(y1, color=c)
    ax.hline(y2, color=c)
    ax.fill_between(ax.get_xlim(), y1, y2, color=c, alpha=0.5)
```

The problem is that this leaves a small amount of blank space to the left and right of the shaded area.

I understand that this is likely due to the plot creating a margin around the used/data area of the plot. So, how do I get the `fill_between` to actually cover the entire plot without matplotlib rescaling the x-axis after drawing? Is there an alternative to `get_xlim` that would give me appropriate limits of the plot, or an alternative to `fill_between`?

This is the current result:

[image: The current result]

Note that this is part of a larger grid layout with several plots, but they all leave a similar margin around these shaded areas.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not strictly speaking an answer to the question of getting the outer limits, but it does solve the problem. Instead of using `fill_between`, I should have used:

```
    ax.axhspan(y1, y2, facecolor=c, alpha=0.5)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`ax.get_xlim()` does return the limits of the axis, not that of the data:

> Axes.get_xlim()
>
> Returns the current x-axis limits as the tuple (left, right).

But Matplotlib simply rescales the x-axis after drawing the `fill_between`:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import numpy as np

pl.figure()
ax=pl.subplot(111)
pl.plot(np.random.random(10))

print(ax.get_xlim())

pl.fill_between(ax.get_xlim(), 0.5, 1)

print(ax.get_xlim())
```

This results in:

> (-0.45000000000000001, 9.4499999999999993)
>
> (-0.94499999999999995, 9.9449999999999985)

If you don't want to manually set the x-limits, you could use something like:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import numpy as np

pl.figure()
ax=pl.subplot(111)
pl.plot(np.random.random(10))

xlim = ax.get_xlim()

pl.fill_between(xlim, 0.5, 1)

ax.set_xlim(xlim)
```

Comment: It think it's a good addition that helps explain what was going on, but I think the answer I provided myself is actually the best answer for someone running into the same problem (i.e. using axhspan instead of fill_between). Do you agree?

Comment: Your solution solved your problem so it is perfectly fine to accept your own answer, my answer was mostly to address your *"... `get_xlim` will return the limits of the data and not the actual plot."*, which is a misunderstanding.

Comment: I actually removed the incorrect assumption, to avoid someone taking the wrong message away from the question.